# Python sockets - auto connect client to server

Tags: python, sockets

I have an application where Python acts as a client talking to another shell (tcl). I would like to have Python connect automatically - I have it all working now but I have to manually do a sock.connect in python. The problem is the tcl shell is started from the Python script in an os.system call:

```
def start_tcl():
    exit_tcl() #Close any existing connections
    server.reset(2540) #Create new socket
    os.system("vivado -mode tcl -source server.tcl") #Open tcl server and connect to socket
```

So if I put connect right after that, the server isn't actually opened yet, and I get endpoint not terminated. Is there a way to have Python wait to connect to the socket once the server is connected? I'm sure I don't fully understand sockets, am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: After you launch the server, you could just have the client try to connect every second until it work, or else timeout (e.g. after 30 seconds).

Comment: True, I was hoping for some fancy way, but maybe this is the only way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up using a while loop in case anyone is interested:
while ( server.connect() is "None" ):
        time.sleep(1)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a while loop in case anyone is interested:

```
    while ( server.connect() is "None" ):
        time.sleep(1)
```

– Kaleb Droskiewicz